# DIFERENCIA HORAS CON PHP

Tags: php

¿cómo podría hacer para que al marcar la opcion de descanso, en el calculo de las horas empleadas, se le reste 45 minutos del descanso al total?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DEFINE('HORA_INICIO', $ini);
DEFINE('HORA_FIN', $fin);
$apertura = new DateTime(HORA_INICIO);
$cierre = new DateTime(HORA_FIN);

$tiempo = $apertura->diff($cierre);

$horas = $tiempo->format('%H:%I');
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la función "modify" sobre el tiempo calculado y indicarle que quieres modificar. En tu caso sería:

```
DEFINE('HORA_INICIO', $ini);
DEFINE('HORA_FIN', $fin);
$apertura = new DateTime(HORA_INICIO);
$cierre = new DateTime(HORA_FIN);

$tiempo = $apertura->diff($cierre);

if($descanso){ //Desconozco el nombre de la variable
     $tiempo->modify('-45 minutes');
}

$horas = $tiempo->format('%H:%I');
```

Para más información para la gestión del tiempo con PHP, [aquí tienes documentación](https://daveismyname.blog/quick-way-to-add-hours-and-minutes-with-php)

Comment: Me da este error la funcion modify(): Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function modify() on string in /var/www/html/forms/submit_iber.php:34